# how do I parameterize an event, in c#

Tags: c#, events

i want to redefine an event, i mean, i have this:

```
boton.Click += infoApp;
//i think thats similar to: boton.Click = new System.EventHandler(infoApp).
```

when button 'boton' is clicked, the function/method 'infoApp' triggers, 
this method its something like this:

```
private void infoApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
/* my code*/
}
```

Until here, evetithing goes well; but I NEED to send another parameter to that method:

```
boton.Click += infoApp(string par)
```

so i thought that this could work:

```
private void infoApp(object sender, EventArgs e, string par)
{
/*My code*/
}
```

but it doesn't.

I've readen things like delegates but i don't understand; and i dont know what to do in order to solve my problem; any ideas?

Thanks in advance

pd: sorry by my terrible english, i'm not english speaker. Try to be simple explaining. I'm using VS2008.

Comment: Where is your required parameter coming from? If it's a property on another control of the form, just fetch the property inside of your event handler?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way you could solve this, would be to wrap your event handler in a closure:

*Instead* of this line:

```
boton.Click += infoApp;
```

Do this:

```
string par = "something";

boton.Click += (sender, e) => {
  //Now call your specific method here:
  infoApp(sender, e, par);
};
```

Comment: +1, and actually you don't even need to include `object` or `EventArgs` unless you're looking for clarity.